# Suggested Edit accepted, reputation given, then removed

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation, deleted-questions

Recently, I edited a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525498/how-to-avoid-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-for-previous-or-next-line), and the edit was accepted, and I got the reputation for it. Several minutes later, I noticed that my reputation had dropped by 2, and the suggested edit was no longer listed as giving me reputation. Furthermore, when I checked back on the post, it was no longer listed as having been edited (by me or by anyone). Also, on the "impact" section on my user-page, under posts edited, it no longer lists that post as one I edited.

Is there some explanation for this? It's only 2 rep, so it's not that big of a deal, but I'm curious why it happened. I changed a large amount of the text (formatting-wise) and the title, so I was wondering if that somehow messed up something?

*Update:*
I also found something else. On the reputation tab, there is the score that tells me how much reputation I have gained since my last visit to the reputation tab. This number differs from the amount listed in this little menu:
[image: Recent Achievements menu]. It is off by 2, which makes me think this number doesn't reflect the missing reputation from the missing edit.

Comment: The other day, I rolled back an edit on a post, saw in the revision history that the rollback had indeed been applied, and a few minutes later... it was gone. It was as if I never rolled it back. I was told that there was indeed a rollback according to the logs but they had no idea why it pretty much just up and vanished. Only reason I didn't pursue it at the time was because the post was deleted anyhow, but it seems this was no isolated incident.

Comment: That's...somewhat disturbing.

Comment: What happened here is as @RobertLongson has suggested...

Comment: Regarding your last point about the rep tab and menu at top of screen differing... this is common, and I assume by design.  The rep tab displays the amount since _you last visited the tab_, the amount on the menu is more easily cleared (eg by expanding the menu).  It's usual for the rep tab to still show a value after the menu was reset.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As confirmed by a moderator in comments, the user deleted their original question and then asked a new identically worded question.

The deletion of the original question meant that the rep you gained from editing it was reverted.

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. What about the indicator of how my rep had changed since my last visit? It doesn't match the amount in the menu. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are existing questions and answers about that. If you read them and are still confused, ask another question here about it.

Comment: @CacheStaheli If you visit the "Reputation" page of your profile, there is a checkbox at the bottom labelled "show removed posts". Checking this, you would see a "removed" event for the post in question.

Comment: @TZHX Didn't know about that. Thanks!